# Puppeteer "userDataDir" from S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, puppeteer

Is it possible to use "userDataDir" of Puppeteer coming from AWS S3 instead of local files?
It turns out that I need to upload user files to S3 because I have a load balance

Answer (score 1):

Chromium expects `userDataDir` to be a local folder that it can read and write to.

However you could mount remote S3 folder locally with solutions like these:

- https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
- https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3

Still the performance of this approach is likely to be quite low. You would probably be better off zipping `userDataDir` folder and downloading/uploading it to S3 before/after work instead.